# Inventory Management System

Tags: web-apps

The thing is that a family friend of mine is opening a shop and he asked me to help him with the inventory (stock) management system.

The system my friend wants to implement it's not very complicated. He wants:

- a server where all the stock data is stored;
- a management PC;
- a cashier PC.

I think a web app will do the job very good as all the computers are connected in LAN.

As I am during the night a web developer, the first thing that came in my mind was to write a module in Drupal that would implement the system he desires. However, I am pretty sure that there is already something out there that I can use, a CMS, a plugin or something alike.

Sadly, I have no idea about anything in this niche. Literally, I don't even know what to search on Google. Nevertheless, googling in my native language was no success, nor using Google Translate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested and would recommend [OpenBravo](http://www.openbravo.com).

It is web-based, so your server would store all data.

Then you can do management and cashier (POS) from any computer.

It is free & open source.

It is a full ERP suite, but you can use only its [inventory management](http://www.openbravo.com/features-erp-platform-inventory-management) feature.